# File changed whilst editing with vi

Tags: vim

I'm using an Ubuntu 20.0.4 machine and connecting via SSH to run `vi`. On more than one occasion, I've had a message when saving the file telling me that the file's contents had changed since I started editing it. If I look at the file on the disk, it has zero length.

I'm the only person using this machine, and if I look at `ps` there's nothing suspicious. I've run the `clamscan` rootkit hunter, and my `.vimrc` file is just set to expand tabs. This is a file with a `~` suffix after the extension of the same name.

Comment: What file are you talking about?

Comment: The Vim editor does not create backups by default (the files with the `~` filename suffix).  Which file exactly are you talking about? Is it private file or a system configuration file (or similar)?

Comment: How can you be saving the file if the file is zero length? Or is that the issue, that _something_ is zeroing the file while you're editing it? What's the actual filename please

Comment: hi the filename is process.rb the issue is that when i edited the file it was 6345 bytes long but when i come back to save the changes it is zero bytes on the disk, so the issue is I think that something is zeroing it on the disk whilst i am editing it. If i start another session i can see the file is zero length. the file is a regular file in my home directory. The server is a lightsail ubuntu